# How to center image in attributed string?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, nsparagraphstyle

I have an `image` that I want to center alongside a bunch of text but even when I set the `NSMutableParagraphStyle` `alignment` to `center`, the line with the image does not center

[image]

If anyone could please help me center the line with the image (i.e. first line) that would be great!

### Code

```
let text = " text next to image is not centered \n\n centered text \n more centered text"
let iconAttachment = textAttachment(fontSize: 14, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon"))
        let iconString = NSAttributedString(attachment: iconAttachment)
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.alignment = .center
        style.minimumLineHeight = 20
        
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()
        attributedText.append(iconString)
        let fullText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style])
        attributedText.append(fullText)

private func textAttachment(fontSize: CGFloat, image: UIImage) -> NSTextAttachment {
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize) //set accordingly to your font, you might pass it in the function
        let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
            textAttachment.image = image
        let mid = font.descender + font.capHeight
        textAttachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: font.descender - image.size.height / 2 + mid + 2, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height).integral
        return textAttachment
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to Alignment your lebel text to center and it will work :

```
 label.textAlignment = .center
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to achieve desire image in center.

```
    let text = "\ntext next to image is not centered \n\n centered text \n more centered text"
    let iconAttachment = textAttachment(fontSize: 5, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "eye"))
    let iconString = NSAttributedString(attachment: iconAttachment)
    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.alignment = .center
    style.minimumLineHeight = 20

    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()
    attributedText.append(iconString)
    let fullText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style])
    attributedText.append(fullText)
    lbl.attributedText = attributedText;
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0
    lbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    lbl.textAlignment = .center
```

**Output**

Note : no change in function

[image]

Comment: This centers the entire label, not just the image attachment.

Comment: Just \n you have to remove from the text from start  @pipacs

Answer (score 0):

You should use .baselineOffset. Depending on your font size, the offSet is varied.

```swift
let image = NSImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "snail")
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = image
let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
mutableAttributedString.addAttributes([.baselineOffset : -2], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: mutableAttributedString.length))
mutableAttributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " Hello World!"))

label.attributedStringValue = mutableAttributedString
```

Result:

[image]